# Trouble installing PyObjc using pip, easy_install, manual

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, easy-install, pyobjc

I'm having a lot of trouble installing PyObjC.  I've tried pip, easy_install, and manual installation and they all give me errors.  I'm trying to use easy_install right now because it is the recommended one from PyObjC's website.

To run I use the command:

```
sudo env CC=clang easy_install -U pyobjc-core
```

I get the following warnings:

```
warning: no directories found matching 'Scripts'
warning: no directories found matching 'setup-lib'
warning: no directories found matching 'source-deps'
warning: no previously-included files matching '.DS_Store' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-mno-fused-madd'
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-mno-fused-madd'
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-mno-fused-madd'
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-mno-fused-madd'
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-mno-fused-madd'
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-mno-fused-madd'
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-mno-fused-madd'
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-mno-fused-madd'
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-mno-fused-madd'
```

along with a ton more errors that are all something like this:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CFXMLNode.h:180:53: error: expected function body after function declarator
CFXMLNodeRef CFXMLTreeGetNode(CFXMLTreeRef xmlTree) CF_DEPRECATED(10_0, 10_8, 2_0, 6_0);
```

Can anyone help me get this installed?

Comment: Which OSX version are you using?

Comment: Can you compile simple C programs with the compiler you are using? The  errors you are getting might indicate that your devtools installation is broken.  What is the *first* error you get during the compilation of pyobjc-core? (BTW. I'm the pyobjc author)

Comment: I'm getting tons of awnings as well

Answer (score 0):

From the errors you are getting I'd say that your compiler installation is broken.

Answer (score 0):

I tried

```
env CC=clang pip install -U pyobjc-core
env CC=clang pip install -U pyobjc
```

And that worked for me. Still got some warnings. Like theses in every package:

```
warning: no directories found matching 'Examples'
warning: no directories found matching 'Modules'
warning: no directories found matching 'source-deps'
warning: no previously-included files matching '.DS_Store' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
```